# convert linq query syntax to method synatx having Contains in where

Tags: c#, linq

I want to convert this query syntax to method syntax, silly but confused

```
List<int> x = new List<int>();
// code to fill list
from ug in DataContext.UserGroups
where (
    from f in x
    select f    
).Contains(ug.ID)
select ug;
```

Comment: what do you mean by method syntax?

Comment: @sleimanjneidi for example DataContext.UserGroups.Where()

Comment: ok you mean a lambda expression

Comment: @Maess method syntax is actually the more appropriate name.  The lambda expression is just the function that the method is using, which is actually a much more broad topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var results = DataContext.UserGroups.Where(ug => x.Contains(ug.ID)).Select(ug => ug.ID);`

I think that's what you want.  The code you put in your question wasn't 100% complete.  Were you just trying to get the IDs of `UserGroups` that were in the int list?  If you just want the `UserGroups` that match, remove the `.Select` part of my query.

To get the `UserGroups` that match:

`var results = DataContext.UserGroups.Where(ug => x.Contains(ug.ID));`

Comment: `var results = DataContext.UserGroups.Where(ug => x.Contains(ug.ID));` is what you want then.  Like I said, just remove the `.Select`.

Comment: No problem.  If there are any parts of the query you don't understand, ask away.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your question correctly, this should give you the result you want:

```
DataContext.UserGroups.Where(ug => x.Contains(ug.Id))
```